# Trouble with a relative route in a wordpress query

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Im using wordpress for a website and i have a problem with these PHP code:

```
global $wpdb;
$proy = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare ("select * from proyectos"));
foreach ( $proy as $proyecto) 
{
$route = $proyecto->ruta; // THE PROBLEM IS WITH THIS 
echo $route;
echo "<div style=background-image: url('".$route."'); class=element data-category=$proyecto->tipo /><p class=number>$proyecto->idP</p><h2 class=name>$proyecto->nombre</h2></div>";
}
```

So, im creating some divs and i want them to load an image as background. Query is correct, the problem is with the $route.

Making `echo $route` shows this: 
`../wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/image.jpg`

now when i make this: `style=background-image: url('".$route."');` and i reload the page it renders this: `style=background-image: url('.. wordpress wp-content uploads 2013 12 image.jpg').` It replaces the `/` for a `blank`.

Please, any help or solutions?

Other valuable info: Im using PHP Code Snippet plugin for wordpress and Chrome browser.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks NoobEditor!! I found the solution finally !! Here is the code:

```
$route ="'".$proyecto->ruta."'";
echo'<div style="height:150px;width:150px;float:left;background-image:url('.$route.')">
<p class=element>$proyecto->tipo</p></div>';
```

It renders the route perfectly and loads the image.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a wordpress guy...but, looks to me that incorrect markup for css is being `echo`ed :

general rule is =>

```
<div style="" ></div>
         __^^__missing these quotes in below lines:
```

`<div style=background-image: url('".$route."'); class=element data-category=$proyecto->tipo /><p class=number>$proyecto->idP</p><h2 class=name>$proyecto->nombre</h2></div>`

change it to :

```
echo '<div style="background-image: url("'.$route.'"); class=element data-category=$proyecto->tipo /><p class=number>$proyecto->idP</p><h2 class=name>$proyecto->nombre</h2></div>';
```

Comment: No, it fails again. Nice try !! echo must start and end with ". If not, $proyecto-idP and $proyecto-nombre don´t give it value.

Comment: @Mikel : in your wp_blogs table, what do you have for the PATH for primary site?

Comment: i might be on old version then!! :)

Comment: But the real is the replacement of / for a blank. If I find a solution for that, this problem is fixed.

Comment: hmmm....that *is* the only problem mate...if i land in a solution, would post in sometime!! :)

Comment: I found the solution finally !! Here is the code:

$route ="'".$proyecto->ruta."'";
echo '<div style="height:150px;width:150px;float:left;background-image:url('.$route.')"><p class=element>$proyecto->tipo</p></div>';

It renders the route perfectly and loads the image.

Comment: help me please, i´m noob in Stackoverflow, how can i post as answer?

Comment: @Mikel : in the question....you would have a tab @ the bottom => **Answer Your Question**...just click and post you answer...i would format it if required :)